# In linear regression model, Is it always necessary that residual mean always closer or equal to zero?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

```
resid = df['Actual'] - df['Predicted']

resid_mean = resid.mean()

print(resid_mean)
```

**Output:**

```
250.8173868583906
```

Is my model predicting value correctly or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your contribution accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression involve minimising the mean squared error (Q) to find the best fitting slope (a) and intercept(b). That is, Q will be minimized at the values of a and b for which ∂Q / ∂a = 0 and ∂Q / ∂b = 0.

The sum of the residuals, and therefore the mean is always zero, for the data that you regressed on. That is one of the above 2 conditions in linear regression.

So, unless you are checking residual mean for data not used in training, there appears to be some mistake in the linear regression procedure you employed.

Detailed proof available here: [http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~kirchner/eps_120/Toolkits/Toolkit_10.pdf](http://seismo.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirchner/eps_120/Toolkits/Toolkit_10.pdf)